# Putting values in Two Dimensional Array

Tags: c++

I am using a double pointer to make a two dimensional array.

```
     int **table;
```

the X axis of table points to Ascii values like show below:
[image]

using the code below I fill up the table

```
  for (int S.no=0; S.no < 20 ; S.no++ )
              {
     for (int ASCII=0; ASCII < 255 ; ASCII++ )
              {
                table[S.no][ASCII]=value; 
               }
                                      }
```

SO, I get something like this:

[image]

Now I want to put value in table for two characters each like below:

[image]

Please help me what value I will put in the ASCII since now the characters are combined. Initially I was putting int ASCII for single char but now what will I do for two characters? as I cannot combine the ASCII of two characters as this will cause problem in accessing the table.

```
       table[S.no][ASCII]=value;
```

Comment: If the x-axis is now more than one char, can you still use `int**`?

Comment: @BrianGradin All I want is to get a single value for two chars each and place that value in single bin. I think int** should work but not sure.

Comment: int** is fine, infact int* is fine too! it depends on how you arrange the data, see the contrast of the two answer. mine represents a more quick-and-dirty way. some people consider this a design flaw in c++

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is what you are looking for, but you could add another dimension to the array:

```
#define NUM_VALUES 20
#define ASCII_RANGE 255

int (*table)[ASCII_RANGE][ASCII_RANGE] = new int[NUM_VALUES][ASCII_RANGE][ASCII_RANGE];

for (int S.no = 0; S.no < NUM_VALUES; S.no++) // S must be a pre-defined class...?
{
    for (int ascii1 = 0; ascii1 < ASCII_RANGE; ascii1++)
    {
        for (int ascii2= 0; ascii2 < ASCII_RANGE; ascii2++)
            table[S.no][ascii1][ascii2] = value; // value = some pre-defined value
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 this is the canonical way but note it gets confusing because of c's array typing.

Comment: Your allocation is wrong: `new int[2][3][4]` produces a value of type `int (*)[3][4]`, not of type `int***`. Even if it did allocate all the ints you need, it would not allocate the index arrays necessary for multilevel pointers. Either use `int (*table)[3][4] = new int[2][3][4];` or allocate your index tables manually.

Answer (score 0):

```
for (int S.no=0; S.no < 20 ; S.no++ )
    for (int ASCII=0; ASCII < 255 ; ASCII++ )
        for (int ASCII_2=0; ASCII_2 < 255 ; ASCII++)
        {
            table[S.no][ASCII << 8 + ASCII_2]=value; 
        }
```

Is that what you mean?

Comment: ...and if you (Zara) aren´t using all 26*26 chars, but only few, consider using a map.